# Unnumbered footnote in Beamer

Tags: beamer, footnotes

I'm looking for the most versatile option to insert a footnote in beamer with no number.

Thanks so much,
Asaf

Answer (score 5):

You could define your own command that yields an unnumbered footnote as shown in the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\newcommand\unfootnote[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \renewcommand\thefootnote{}\footnote{#1}%
  \addtocounter{footnote}{-1}%
  \endgroup
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
Some text\unfootnote{An unnumbered footnote} \footnote{a numbered footnote}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you @leandriis. I tried your code but the footnotes do not appear. When I change to \footnote[frame]{a numbered footnote}, a numbered footnote shows; but I don't know how to change the \unfootnote command definition accordingly. Thank you!

Comment: I have edited my answer to include an image of the output. As you can see, the footnotes are printed as expected. Do you encouter the problem with the MWE or with your actual document? Also, why do you need the `[frame]` option? According to the `beamer` documentation, it is the default behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

The footnote number can be removed with a slight adjustment of beamers footnote template:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamertemplate{footnote}{%
  \parindent 1em\noindent%
  \raggedright
  \insertfootnotetext\par%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

text \footnotetext{A test footnote in the first column}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]