# How to remove footnote marker (number) in Beamer?

Tags: beamer

Hi This is my minimal working environment:

```
\documentclass[compress]{beamer}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}
\subsection{Germanium Catenates}
\begin{frame}[t]{\ce{Ge-F} Containing Compounds} \vspace{20pt}

\begin{itemize}

\item There are 134 compounds in total that contain \ce{Ge-F} bond.

\begin{figure}[ht]

\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{Figures/Images1.png}
\end{figure}


\end{itemize}
\footnotetext[1]{{\tiny A test footnote in the first column}}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

How can I remove that marker number?

It looks like this:

[image]

Also, when I used [this solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/408750/unnumbered-footnote-in-beamer) it ended up like this:

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As an alternative to the great answer from @marmot, you could also use beamers own mechanism to change the appearance of the footnote.

To change the size of the text:

```
\setbeamerfont{footnote}{size=\tiny}
```

To get an unnumbered footnote:

```
\setbeamertemplate{footnote}{%
  \parindent 1em\noindent%
  \raggedright
  \insertfootnotetext\par%
}
```

Both of these settings can either be applied globally (like in the example below) or locally for only one footnote if used inside a group.

Please also note that you don't need any floating specifier for your `figure` environment in a class that does not have floats.

```
\documentclass[compress]{beamer}

\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}

\setbeamerfont{footnote}{size=\tiny}

\setbeamertemplate{footnote}{%
  \parindent 1em\noindent%
  \raggedright
  \insertfootnotetext\par%
}

\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}
\subsection{Germanium Catenates}
\begin{frame}[t]{\ce{Ge-F} Containing Compounds} \vspace{20pt}

\begin{itemize}

\item There are 134 compounds in total that contain \ce{Ge-F} bond.

\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{example-image-duck}
\end{figure}


\end{itemize}

\footnotetext{A test footnote in the first column}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to TeX.SE! All you need to do is to use the `\blfootnote` command from [this nice answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/30726/121799). BTW, if you use the `beamer` class, there is no need to load the `graphicx` package. I also do not see where you are using the `mhchem` package, but I kept it to show that there is no conflict.

```
\documentclass[compress]{beamer}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\newcommand\blfootnote[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \renewcommand\thefootnote{}\footnote{#1}%
  \addtocounter{footnote}{-1}%
  \endgroup
}

\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}
\subsection{Germanium Catenates}
\begin{frame}[t]{\ce{Ge-F} Containing Compounds} \vspace{20pt}

\begin{itemize}

\item There are 134 compounds in total that contain \ce{Ge-F} bond.

\begin{figure}[ht]

\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{example-image-duck}
\end{figure}


\end{itemize}
\blfootnote{\tiny A test footnote in the first column}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice answer! The `mhchem` package is used in the frametitle for `\ce{Ge-F}`