# Remove footnote number when using biblatex footcite within beamer

Tags: beamer, biblatex

I am preparing a presentation with beamer and using biblatex `\footcite`. I want to remove associated footnote numbers for all these citations. I have tried solutions that are posted for general footnotes, but they just don't work for me:

- [How to remove footnote marker (number) in Beamer?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/455917/how-to-remove-footnote-marker-number-in-beamer)
- [Footnote without a marker](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30720/footnote-without-a-marker)

I managed to remove the number within the footnote, but not the number in the text. I attach here an example code where I cite from frame title and from frame content.

How can I do it?

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{website:test,
author = "Favorite Author",
title = "My wonderful test page",
month = "8",
year = "2018",
url = "https://this.my.net/web-page.html"
}
@article{Author2006,
author = {Author, First and Other, Second},
doi = {10.1111/science.1111111},
issn = {00111111},
journal = {Science},
number = {5111},
pages = {111--122},
publisher = {American Association for the Advancement of Science},
title = {{My favorite article I want to cite}},
volume = {301},
year = {2006}
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[backend=biber,style=verbose]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\usetheme{Boadilla}

\setbeamertemplate{footnote}{
  \parindent 1em\noindent
  \raggedright
  \insertfootnotetext\par
}

\begin{document}
\title{Presentation Title}
\subtitle{Presentation Subtitle}
\author{My name}
\institute{ABC University}
\date[\today]{\today}

\frame{\titlepage}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{First Frame \footcite{Author2006}}
Some text.
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Second Frame}
Some more text.
\footcite{website:test}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]
\frametitle<presentation>{References}
\printbibliography
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are never going to need footnote marks, the easiest way is to just remove them completely with

```
\makeatletter
\def\@makefnmark{}
\makeatletter
```

MWE

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[backend=biber,style=verbose]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\usetheme{Boadilla}

\makeatletter
\def\@makefnmark{}
\makeatletter

\setbeamertemplate{footnote}{%
  \parindent 1em\noindent
  \raggedright
  \insertfootnotetext\par
}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{First Frame \footcite{sigfridsson}}
Some text.
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Second Frame}
Some more text.
\footcite{worman}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]
\frametitle<presentation>{References}
\printbibliography
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: Frame with citation in the foot. No footnote mark is to be seen anywhere.]

Comment: It works! For future reference: The code modifying the beamer template is still necessary, otherwise it indents the footnote. Thanks!