# Selectively removing footnote number with footcite in beamer

Tags: beamer, biblatex, citing

My question is identical to [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/488267/remove-footnote-number-when-using-biblatex-footcite-within-beamer), which asks how to remove footnote numbers from the footcite command within Beamer. The accepted answer, which is the command

```
\makeatletter
\def\@makefnmark{}
\makeatletter
```

removes the numbering completely. I would like to be able to remove the numbering selectively, and show the numbers on some slides while hiding it on others. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

If you make the modifications inside a group, only the frames in this group will be effected:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[backend=biber,style=verbose]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\usetheme{Boadilla}



\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{First Frame \footcite{sigfridsson}}
Some text.
\end{frame}

\begingroup
  \makeatletter
  \def\@makefnmark{}
  \makeatletter
  \setbeamertemplate{footnote}{%
    \parindent 1em\noindent
    \raggedright
    \insertfootnotetext\par
  }
  
  \begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Second Frame}
  Some more text.
  \footcite{worman}
  \end{frame}
\endgroup

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{First Frame \footcite{sigfridsson}}
Some text.
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]
\frametitle<presentation>{References}
\printbibliography
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```