# Beamer Metropolis Section Page Footnote Without Mark

Tags: beamer, footnotes, metropolis

I want to write a text below the progress bar in a section page in the `metropolis` theme.
I found out that, to some extend, footnotes could serve as a solution. However I did not achieve to remove the footnote numbering. I tried some question/answer pairs, e.g., [Footnote without a marker](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30720/footnote-without-a-marker), [How to remove footnote marker (number) in Beamer?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/455917/how-to-remove-footnote-marker-number-in-beamer), [Footnote without a marker](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30720/footnote-without-a-marker). But was not successful, as either it gave errors, or, while it removed the footnote marker at the footnotetext, the indicator stayed at the place where the footnote was placed.

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{metropolis}
\renewcommand\footnoterule{}

\begin{document}

\section{over the section bar\footnote{under the section bar}}

\begin{frame}

text 

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

This produces the following (I want both a's to disappear):
[image: screenshot from compilated LaTeX code]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could temporarily add your text to the end of the `section page` template (you might have to fine-tune the lengths to put the text exactly where you want it):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{moloch}% modern fork of the metropolis theme
\renewcommand\footnoterule{}

\begin{document}

{
\addtobeamertemplate{section page}{}{\vskip-1cm\hspace{1.1cm}\usebeamerfont{footnote}\usebeamercolor[fg]{footnote}under the section bar}
\section{over the section bar}
}

\begin{frame}

text 

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for pointing out `moloch`!

Comment: @Arne Moloch it is a great theme and avoids most of the problems of metropolis, like this one for which beamer has to patch patches of patches just to keep metropolis from breaking completely https://github.com/matze/mtheme/issues/393#issuecomment-1562908382